# If $ x^2=b$ and order of $b$ is $3$, is order of $x$ necessarily of order $6$?

Tags: group-theory

Quoted here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAIvhUZuQRo&list=PLF379B0552AD17780&index=18

I can only induce that the order of the element must divide 6, not necessarily 6.

[image]

Comment: Please do not write the full question in the title. Also please be a bit more precise. Which power of an element? Do you know anything about the group? This would be useful.

Comment: It's a short question, I just edited the title to be more precise.

Comment: @includeCMath On the contrary, when the full title can be written easily in the question it is _much_ preferred. The title should contain as much information as possible about the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a\in G$,  $n:=\text{o}(a)$. Notice that $\text{o}(a^2)=\frac{n}{gcd(n,2)}$ and $\text{o}(a^2)=3$ . So the statement is false, the order of the element could be also 3. For example in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$, 2 has order 3 and in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, 2 has order 6, while 4 has order 3 in both of them

Comment: Seems both 6 and 3 are a solution.

Comment: Yeah but order of an element is the least natural $k$ such as $a^k=1_{G}$, so it's 3

Comment: No, both are possible. Two different cases.

Comment: Yes, sorry. For example in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ 2 has order 3 and in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ 2 has order 6, while 4 has order 3 in both of them

Answer (score 0):

You have $b^2=a$ and $ord(b)=3$ thus $b^3=(a^2)^3)=a^6=1$ therefore $ord(a)|6$ but $ord(a)\neq 2$ since then $b$ would have order $1$.

Let us consider $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},+)$. If $a=1$ then $a^2 = 2$ and $ord(2)=3$ and we have $ord(a)=ord(1)=6$. If $a=4$ then $a^2=2$ but $ord(4)=3$. So both cases are possible.

Note that it would be better/more convinient to write $a^2$ as $2a$ in this case but i wanted to keep the "power notation" here.

Answer (score 0):

No. In $S_3$, $(123)^2=(132)$. Both elements have order $3$.